# Getting an error while running Runtime.exec method in java

Tags: java, runtime, runtime.exec

I am using java program to run priyam.bat file which is i placed in D:/priyam.bat directory but while running this java program i am getting the below error .

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "priyam.bat" (in directory "D:\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:470)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:431)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:177)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:28)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:452)
    ... 3 more
```

**Snippet of code**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Test {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    int arg = 5;
    try {
        Process p = r.exec("priyam.bat",null,new File("D://"));
        System.out.println("executed");


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As i am new to the java world,your help and suggestions will be highly lauded and appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: `The system cannot find the file specified.` Isn't it self-explanatory?

Comment: The exception message is clear enough. What do you not understand about it?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
Process p = r.exec("D:\\priyam.bat"));
```

In windows the file separator is "\" or you can use File.separator value.

Comment: Thanks Ipman1971 , now code is working and successfully running but .bat file is not opening .just like when we double click on bat file ,console pops up but why it is not happening here ?

Comment: What do you expect? You have a `Process` object and you can read the `stdout` of the process from that object if you want to process the output of your `priyam.bat`. Please, explain what you want to do in more detail.